# How Do I Auto Clip Text When Google Form Is Submitted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Hope you are having a pleasant Sunday. Hoping someone can help me out with something that seems kinda odd. I have a Google Form that collects responses on a Google sheet, all works grand apart from the fact that the text is not clipped when submitted.

I have made all cells clip and that works fine unless a new form response comes through. Is there anyway when a new response is submitted it auto clips the cells in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Do you have code that you can share?  Can you show or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be support for programmatically setting clipping since the new sheets update a while back. This is probably also the reason why clipping is undone whenever a new row is added. There are few bug reports related to this issue that you can search for and star for a solution.

Comment: Ah..... Not good. I wonder if wrapped text also has this issue. Will give this a go now.

Comment: I believing wrapping text works. I've done this before in the distant past, don't remember off the top of my head at the momment though.